# Can I use a Hashtable as a return value of a function?

Tags: java, function, parameters, hashtable, return-value

I have a loop that goes through the content of different files, and I'm creating a hashtable that I want to use for all of them (as a continuity). I thought using a function and sending the hashtable as a parameter, and also use it as a return value.

```java
public static *** function1(*** hashtable)
{
   /*

...

    */
    return hashtable;
}
```

Sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. but my question is if it's feasible, what should I write in the ***?

Comment: Yes you can (although it might not be the best idea), you need to know which data types you're using as key and value however. See [Docs: Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). If you use a `String` for both the type will be `Hashtable<String, String>` at both ***.

Comment: "_Can I use a Hashtable as a return value of a function?_"—Yes, of course. Are you facing some kind of difficulty doing that?

Comment: Use Map<K,V> in place of the ***** where K is the type of the key and V is the type of the value. You can also use Hashtable<K,V> but it is bad practice to use concrete classes over interfaces when declaring arguments.

Comment: In Java, the type is normally called a `HashMap`.  Try putting that for the `***` and tell us the result.

Comment: You could use `Hashtable` in place of `***`. But, it is regarded as bad practice to use raw types in new code. Instead, use generics. This is an additional reason the comment from @JohnWilliams is good.

Comment: Yes. In Java, a method may return a primitive, an object, an array of primitives, or an array of Objects. The declared return type may be any of those, or an interface.  Since a `Hashtable` is a type of Object, a return type of `Hashtable` is valid.

Comment: @markspace I would even argue it is better to use `Map` in the method signature instead of a specific type

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a Hashtable as a return value of a function?

Yes.

You can define your method to return a reference to any kind of object you want. That reference could point to an instance of a `Hashtable` if you so desire.

See *The Java Tutorials* provided free-of-cost by Oracle: [*Returning a Value from a Method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

As for [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html), that class was supplanted decades ago by other implementations of `Map` such as [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). The Javadoc for that class explains.

In Java, a function is called a “method”.

Below is an example of a method returning a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). Following your lead, we have a `static` method defined on a class called `App`. By the way, be aware that `static` means "not object-oriented".

Notice the angle-brackets (`<` & `>`) to specify the type of our map’s keys and the type of our map’s values. The compiler can then enforce [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Here we specify that every key must be an reference to an instance of a `String`, and every value must be a reference to a [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) object.

For this example, we use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) to generate an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) `Map` object of an unspecified [concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) class while using [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) syntax.

```java
public static Map < String, DayOfWeek > fetchEmployeeToDayOfWeekMap ( )
{
    return
            Map.of(
                    "Alice" , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ,  // key , value ,
                    "Bob" , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ,     // key , value ,
                    "Carol" , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY    // key , value 
            );
}
```

Example calling that method.

```
Map < String, DayOfWeek > empToDayMap = App.fetchEmployeeToDayOfWeekMap();
```

Generating text representing the content of that map.

```
System.out.println( "empToDayMap.toString() = " + empToDayMap );
```

> empToDayMap.toString() = {Alice=TUESDAY, Bob=MONDAY, Carol=TUESDAY}